# How to index image list by name instead of position?

Tags: c#, combobox, windows-forms-designer, imagelist

I'm very new to C# and am working on Visual Studios Express 2012 on Windows 7.

I have an imagelist of images with the names `"a"`, `"b"`, `"c"`, and I have a combo box with the options `"a"`, `"b"`, and `"c"`.

I'm trying to add the image corresponding to the combobox selection to a picturebox.

Originally I was using the position rather than name like so:

```
         int i = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
         pictureBox1.Image = imageList1.Images[i];
```

However, I thought there might later be changes to the combo box options and they might not be in the same order anymore, so I want to do it by name instead of position.

I tried this:

```
         string name = comboBox1.SelectedText;
         int i = imageList1.Images.IndexOfKey(name);
         pictureBox1.Image = imageList1.Images[i];
```

But this results in runtime errors `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException ... InvalidArgument=Value of '-1' is not valid for 'index'`.

I was also thinking something like this might work:

```
         string grade = comboBox1.SelectedText;
         pictureBox1.Image = imageList1.ImageCollection.IndexOfKey(grade);
```

or

```
         pictureBox1.Image = ImageList.ImageCollection.IndexOfKey(grade);
```

But these give me compiler errors

```
'ImageCollection': cannot reference a type through an expression; 
 try 'System.Windows.Forms.ImageList.ImageCollection'
```

and

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 
'System.Windows.Forms.ImageList.ImageCollection.IndexOfKey(string)'
```

How should I go about doing this? Suggestions for alternative methods?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: pictureBox1.Image = imageList1.Images[comboBox1.SelectedText];

Comment: @216, that doesn't give me any errors, but no images are appearing in the pictureBox1. Now that you point it out though, I see that visual studios gives a second definition for that and allows for keys, not just indeces. So you're right that should work.

Comment: How are you populating the imageList?

Comment: I'm doing it in the form designer. I just did a MessageBox.Show to see the value of `comboBox1.selectedText` and it's an empty string for some reason. I'm running the code in `comboBox1_selectedIndexChanged`

Comment: wtf, the images show up when I do a MessageBox before the line you gave me (which still returns an empty string), but not if I comment it out.

Comment: Then, you're including the file extension in the name of the image

Comment: Try  imageList1.Images[comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()];

Comment: Still working with an empty message box but not if it's commented out. I don't think the extension is included though because I rename the files in the imageList1 members to just a, b, and c though.

Comment: Just use imageList1.Images[comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()]; remove any breakbpoint or messagebox

Comment: You're right, the ToString() works. I'm not sure what was going on before with it not working without a messagebox but it's fixed now. Thanks.

Comment: May I post the answer would you mark it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```
imageList1.Images[comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()];
```

remove any breakbpoint or messagebox

Answer (score 2):

I have tried Tuco's solution and ended up in the same error.

By trying I found my solution... so I provide this for all who not solved the problem with the given solution.

In my case it was a Treeview called `tvFiles`

```
/* Fill/Define the TreeViews ImageList */
tvFiles.ImageList   = imageList1;
/* Set the Index by Imagename */
tvFiles.ImageIndex  = imageList1.Images.IndexOfKey(imgName);
```

Comment: The "real" solution, plus 1